# How to dynamically replace string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have this string:

```
var text1 = "Ferrari Mercedes Ferrari Android iPhone LG iPhone iOS";
//text1 could be anything
```

I have these arrays:

```
var cars = ['Toyota', 'BMW', 'Ferrari', 'Mercedes'];
var phones = ['Nokia', 'Samsung', 'LG', 'iPhone'];
// cars values are fixed, but number of array could be increased
```

I want to replace each word in `text1` with one of the words/values in an array that has a same value, example:

1. The word *Ferrari* in `text1` will match one of `Cars` values, so it will be replaced randomly either by *BMW*, *Toyota*, or *Mercedes* but not *Ferrari* nor one of the `phones` values. (let say it was replaced randomly by *BMW*)
2. The second *Ferrari* word will also replaced by *BMW*
3. But the *Mercedes* word in `text1` must not replaced by *BMW* and *Mercedes*
4. and also the same terms applied for words in `text1` that categorized in `phones`
5. I expect the result could be something like:

`text1 = "BMW Toyota BMW Android Nokia Samsung Nokia iOS";`

6. *Android* and *iOS* are not replaced because they are not on any list of array.

What is the effective way to get this?

Comment: Ok, post your attempts.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a help desk.  Try something then if you can't get your code to work, post the code you tried.

Comment: no, I don't have the attempts yet, I just start to imagine, split each words in text1 then loops through regex, but too much regex make my laptop run slow yesterday with different case.. this is just my imagination logic after i saw game on my friends phones, i'm 9 yo so i think i have to much useless imagination like this, im sorry for asking like this

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I never ask for any code, I just wanna help from you guys about an effective way to do this (is it workflow or flowchart, yes?) my school doesnt teach this yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it.

1. Randomly generate two 'offset' numbers between 1 and the length of your arrays (cars/phones)
2. Create an empty 'mapper' hash to store your mapping of old-new names
3. Loop through all the index values in your cars array, adding a value to your 'namemapper' with the key = cars[index] and value = cars[index + offset % cars.length], this will ensure that each old name is mapped to a distinct, new name
4. Do the same thing for phones
5. Split the string on ' ' to get an array of words (I called this splitText)
6. Define an empty answer string and both = phones + cars
7. Use a for loop to access every value of splitText
8. Within this for-loop, check if each word is in the 'both' array, you can do this by using a second for loop to access every string in the array and check for equality using ===
9. If it is, append the value corresponding to this key in your mapper to the answer string
10. Otherwise, append the splitString value to your answer string
11. Add a space

Here's the code:

```
var carOffset = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (cars.length-1));
var phoneOffset = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (phones.length -1));
var mapper = {};

for(var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++){
    j = (i + carOffset) % cars.length;
    mapper[cars[i]]=cars[j];
}
for(var i = 0; i < phones.length; i++){
    j = (i + phoneOffset) % phones.length;
    mapper[phones[i]]=phones[j];
}

var splitText = text1.split(' ');
var ansString = '';
var both = cars + phones;
for(var i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++){
    var flag = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j< both.length; j++){
        if(splitText[i]===both[j]){
            ansString += mapper[splitText[i]];
            flag += 1;
        }
    }
    if(flag === 0){
        ansString += splitText[i];
    }
    ansString += ' ';
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll try the logic, i really appreciate your time to teach me, thank you

Comment: Sorry, I've had another look and am not sure this is exactly what you wanted. I'll try and get back to you...

Comment: I think this updated solution does now answer the question.

Comment: I don't try your code yet, just run it in my head right now I love the technique especially #3. there are two ways i think for doing string matching pattern, looping or regex afaik from what i read on others quostions in stackoverflow, I might regex on this one, i need more dynamic probability, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I would use this workflow:

1. Define your RegEx for each object type: rxCars:
   \(toyota|bmw|ferrari|mercedes)\gi
2. Get matches for the given text1
3. Define a JavasScript Associative Array to contain Mathc/Replacement pairs
4. Iterate through matches, checking in the Associative Array... if (associativeArray["toyota"] != null){}
   If it's NEW select a random replacement item from the cars array, and remove that item from the cars array.
   If it already exists, skip and go on to the next MATCH.
5. After you've checked each match, iterate through your associative array, performing replacements for each item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to avoid regex, because yesterday my laptop runs slow while trying too much regex, with different case, if it's inevitable, i'll try the regex

Comment: When you say "with different case", do you mean using patterns for alternate case? Should use case-insensitive pattern: //i at end.

Comment: No, I mean, different program I tried to built text searching yesterday, this one is entirely different program

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i'll try to built the code